# Handler method is not getting considered

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-security

I have below code

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/xyz")
public class MyController {

@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET, value = "/abc")
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
@ResponseBody   
public void myMethod(String pqr) {
    ....
    ....
}
....
....
```

I am making an AJAX request  /contextname/xyz/abc

but the handler method declared above is not being considered, I am getting the below error

```
DEBUG o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet - DispatcherServlet with name           
'contextname' processing GET request for    
[http://mydomain:8085/contextname/xyz/abc]

00:22:32.867 [http-nio-8080-exec-1] DEBUG    
o.s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping - Looking up handler method for 
path /abc
00:22:32.916 [http-nio-8080-exec-1] DEBUG    
o.s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping - Did not find handler method for 
[/abc]
00:22:32.916 [http-nio-8080-exec-1] WARN  o.s.web.servlet.PageNotFound - No    
mapping found for HTTP request with URI   
[http://mydomain:8085/contextname/xyz/abc] in DispatcherServlet with name  
'contextname'
```

any suggestions ?

Comment: can you add your web.xml, dispatcher-servlet.xml and project structure ?

Answer (score 0):

remove `String pqr` parameter, spring doesnt know what to inject there.

Answer (score 0):

Change the signature of the method to...

```
public void myMethod(@RequestParam(required=false) String pqr)
```

...if you want to occasionally send that parameter and your method is not dependent on it.

Spring doesn't know which value to pass to the method.